# Need to change a sentence to add a word from a list in separate sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Hi there and thank you for any support received in advance!

I have a [Google Sheets document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vKc1u1B_Yz8MOUX7x1dRucrKZepozqft18N_jkVAgX8/edit?usp=sharing) that has a list of towns in it in two columns on a separate tab and a series of default statements.

I would like to be able to run some form of script or code that automatically changes the "XXXX" and the "ZZZZ" to the appropriate text, as listed in the list of towns (on the second sheet) in any sentence and replaces it with a word from the list of towns. If someone is able to help I would really appreciate it and you can change that document as much as you'd like (it is a demo that I have set up for the purpose of asking this question). I would also appreciate a short explanation as to how you achieve the required result so I can learn and apply this in the future (without having to come back to S.O every time).

NOTE: I need to apply this for 1719 rows in the sheet, and cascade all of the text down it.

Edit: I have completed the first line of the sheet and completed it to the way we need it to be.

Comment: Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Hi Ruben, I previously tried using this:

=Arrayformula(if(len(A3:A), substitute(B2:C2, "XXXXXX",A3:A),))

- This was on a different sheet with a different layout, so I think the principle of using the Array Formula could work, but I was not able to change the position of the variables, or discriminate between the XXXX and XXXXXX by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `XXXXXX` to `ZZZZ` and use newest formula

`=arrayformula(if(len(C3:C), substitute(substitute(B2, "XXXX",list!A2:A),"ZZZZ",list!B2:B),))`

Now no mixing `XXXX` and `XXXXXX`

For column `B` put this formula in cell `B3`.
For column `D` put formula in cell `D3` and only change `B2` to `D2`.
For column `F` put formula in cell `F3` and only change `B2` to `F2`.
For column `L` put formula in cell `L3` and only change `B2` to `L2`.
For column `M` put formula in cell `M3` and only change `B2` to `M2`.  etc.
Like this do for every column you need.

Like other question now you do it 2 times. One for `XXXX` and one more for `ZZZZ`. That is why you do `substitute` again.
Because it is other tab you use `list!` for ranges there.

Comment: Sorry but this does not achieve the desired effect. I placed that formula into cell B3 on 'Pages' sheet, but it returned a full sentence rather than the replaced text that I needed. If someone could help with a solution to this or make direct changes on a "Copy Sheet" that would be great.

Comment: You try this answer @ManrajSandhu ? It works.

Comment: When I do this (as you can see in the spreadsheet) it is only using the first option from the list sheet

Comment: I have tried the changes you suggested but the sheet is now showing all of the results using the same feed of data from 'List' sheet, in row 2

Comment: I fixed the sheet. You made mistake and change values in also B2. Row 2 must have values with `XXXX` and `ZZZZ`. Or nothing works. You can accept answer now.